# Double grepping two files against each other in Python?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Maybe what I mean is not so much "double grepping" but "approximate string matching" or "fuzzy text matching"? Basically I want to have a program that acts like grep, but searches for phrases of length X that appear in roughly the same form in two texts, and returns those phrases with their original context. This is what I have so far. (It's also up on [this ipython notebook, with sample output](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/text-matcher/blob/master/matching-experiments.ipynb).

```
import nltk
import re
from nltk.util import ngrams
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from string import punctuation
from termcolor import colored
from fuzzysearch import find_near_matches

class Matcher: 
    def __init__(self, fileA, fileB, threshold, ngramSize):
        """
        Gets the texts from the files, tokenizes them, 
        cleans them up as necessary. 
        """
        self.threshold = threshold

        self.filenameA = fileA
        self.filenameB = fileB

        self.textA = self.readFile(fileA)
        self.textB = self.readFile(fileB)

        textATokens = self.tokenize(self.textA)
        textBTokens = self.tokenize(self.textB)

        self.textAgrams = list(ngrams(textATokens, ngramSize))
        self.textBgrams = list(ngrams(textBTokens, ngramSize))

    def readFile(self, filename): 
        """ Reads the file in memory. """
        return open(filename).read()

    def tokenize(self, text): 
        """ Tokenizes the text, breaking it up into words. """
        return nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower())

    def gramsToString(self, grams): 
        """
        Takes a list of tuples (3-grams, 4-grams, etc.) 
        and stitches it back together into a string, so that
        we can search the non-tokenized text for the string later. 
        """
        string = " ".join(grams[0][:-1])
        for gram in grams:
            lastGram = gram[-1]
            if lastGram not in punctuation: 
                string += " " + lastGram
            else: 
                string += lastGram
        return string

    def getMatch(self, match, textA, textB): 
        """ 
        Takes the match object returned by get_matching_blocks() and
        gets the matched n-gram. It uses gramsToString() to 
        reformat this into a string.
        """
        textAs, textBs = [], []
        for i in range(match.size):
            textAs.append(textA[match.a+i])
            textBs.append(textB[match.b+i])
        return (self.gramsToString(textAs), self.gramsToString(textBs))

    def match(self): 
        """
        This does the main work of finding matching n-gram sequences between
        the texts.
        """
        sequence = SequenceMatcher(None,self.textAgrams,self.textBgrams)
        matchingBlocks = sequence.get_matching_blocks()

        # Only return the matching sequences that are higher than the 
        # threshold given by the user. 
        highMatchingBlocks = [match for match in matchingBlocks if match.size > self.threshold]

        for match in highMatchingBlocks: 
            out = self.getMatch(match, self.textAgrams, self.textBgrams)
            print('\n', out)
            self.findInText(out[0], self.textA, self.filenameA, 20)
            self.findInText(out[1], self.textB, self.filenameB, 20)

    def findInText(self, needle, haystack, haystackName, context):
        """
        This takes the matches found by match() and tries to find that match
        again in the text, so that we can return some context. Uses the
        fuzzysearch library, because I couldn't find anything better.
        """
        m = find_near_matches(needle, haystack, max_l_dist=2)

        if len(m) > 0: 
            m = m[0] # just get the first match for now. TODO: get all of them

            before = haystack[m.start-context:m.start]
            match  = colored(haystack[m.start:m.end], 'red')
            after  = haystack[m.end:m.end+context]    

            contextualized = before + match + after
            cleaned = re.sub( '\s+', ' ', contextualized ).strip()
            print(colored(haystackName, 'green') + ": " + cleaned)
        else: 
            print('Couldn\'t find this match in file: ', haystackName)
```

Usage:

```
myMatch = Matcher('milton.txt', 'kjv.txt', 2, 3)
myMatch.match()
```

It mostly works, but it's pretty awkward, since it has to 1) find a matching string with n-grams, and 2) figure out where in the text those n-grams came from. Sometimes the program will find a match, but then it can't figure out where in the original text that match corresponds to. If there's a way to just search the files themselves to begin with, and not search a list of n-grams, then this whole thing could be simplified. Is there a way to do that? Alternatively, is there a way to associate the n-grams list with their positions in the original text?

Comment: When building the ngram list, create a dictionary with the n-gram as the key and the position in the original text as a list of values.

Comment: But how would I get the position in the original text?

Comment: How did you get the ngrams in the first place? Didn't you get them from the original text? When you add an ngram from into the list, save the location in the text at the same time. You should know where you are copying it from.

Comment: `span_tokenize()` gives you start/end offsets of each token.

Comment: Thanks, @lenz. How do I use it? `nltk.span_tokenize()` doesn't seem to exist, and elsewhere in NLTK it looks unimplemented.

Comment: Not all of the tokenizer classes implement a `span_tokenize()` method, but some do, eg. the _Punkt_ one: `wt = nltk.tokenize.PunktWordTokenizer(); wt.span_tokenize(sentence)`. It expects the text to be sentence-split already, so you should probably do that first, too.

Comment: There is no `nltk.tokenize.PunktWordTokenizer()`, from what I can tell, just `nltk.tokenize.PunktSentenceTokenizer()`.

Comment: That's peculiar – it was there in NLTK version 3.0.0, but it's gone in 3.1. You can use `WordPunctTokenizer` instead, it also implements the `span_tokenize()` method.